# "it may/might interest you to know that" vs. "it may be of interest that..."

Tags: differences, syntactic-analysis

Is there any difference between the following structures ?

> 1 .It may be of interest that I’ve changed my opinion on that
>   matter.
>
> 2.It might interest you to learn that I’ve changed my opinion on that
>   matter.

[Sentence 2](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/interest_2) is from McMillan Dictionary.

Comment: "You may/might be interested to know/learn that..." is more idiomatic.

Comment: You're also forgetting the discovery part in the first sentence "of interest to you to *know/hear/learn* that.."

Comment: I think this question might get more helpful answers on ELL.

Comment: @MorganFR do you think  without a " you" or an object pronoun the first sentence sounds incomplete.. I also saw sentences using this structure continue with infinitive  ...

Comment: If you don't add "to you", then we don't know whose interest it is. It could be interesting for me to tell you, or for you to know. you need the "to someone" to know whose interest is at stake. Could be you, me, us, them, my dog, or whoever else. Otherwise, the interest is general, but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I see your point. How about this sentence I saw when I looked it up in a corpus: "It may be of interest to know something about the development and program of one American branch campus in Japan." I think here is the sense that "some people may interest " or maybe " it is interesting to know ..." ?

Comment: You've stumbled upon another meaning of "(of) interest" with that one. In your new sentence, "of interest" means that it's beneficial (to anyone), whereas the rest of the sentences we've discussed so far where about interest as in "curiosity, concern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between *may* and *might* in this construction, so let's just use *might*, OK?
Then we can start by noting that *to you* is optional in

- *It might be of interest **(to you**) that I’ve changed my opinion on that matter.*

But the *you* is obligatory in

- *It might interest **you** to learn that I’ve changed my opinion on that matter.*

since it's ungrammatical without it.

- **It might interest to learn that I’ve changed my opinion on that matter.*

Note also that there's an extra clause in the second sentence that doesn't occur in the first one,
or it would look like this:

- *It might be of interest **(for you) to learn** that I’ve changed my opinion on that matter.*

The *learn* clause can be omitted without changing the meaning, however:

- *It might interest you that I’ve changed my opinion on that matter.*

since *learn* only refers to *coming to know*, and *interest* already presupposes *know*.

Once these accidental differences between the examples are dispensed with, the difference that remains -- the general/indefinite sense for *be of interest* vs the specifically-addressed sense of *interest s.b.* -- are due to the difference between the grammar of *interest* as the noun object of a predicate prepositional phrase *be of interest*, and the grammar of *interest* as a verb. Verbal syntax is significantly more complex than nominal syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there isn't a strong difference between *may do* and *might do* in the present. Generally, *might have* appears a slimmer, more remote chance of happening.

For your sentences, I would read the first one as a more solid expectation that the "change of opinion" will interest the addressee. Perhaps the addressee had been trying to convince the speaker for some time to change his mind. This would likely be welcome news!

As for the second, I would probably employ it over *may* if, for example, the addressee hadn't tried to change my mind; rather, I am just updating them on my new state.